# Set html text into textarea js

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a textarea where i need to set some html text

```
<textarea id="text"></textarea>
<div id="elem">
  <p>text</p>
  <hr />
  <br />
  <p> some text</p>
</div>
..
$('#text').val($('#elem').html());
```

when I do this it's put text with html tags instead of parse it and put like a plain text.
i also tried functions `append(), html(), text()`. none of them helps me

Comment: What text do you specifically need? Everything in `elem`?

Comment: Your code the way it is will place the raw html in your textbox. If you want it to put just the text without the tags, use $('#elem').text()

Comment: OP already tried that. Clearly he wants something else.

Comment: What do you want the textarea to contain ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend to use a `contenteditable` `div` element instead of a `textarea` as follows:

```
<div class="text-area" contenteditable>
    <h1>Your content here</h1>
</div>
```

See [JSfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/58b1dp02/)

Answer (score 1):

`text()` worked for me. See https://jsfiddle.net/mgLp90em/.

What is the jQuery version you are using?

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick, gets only text from the children within your `#elem`:

```
$('#text').val($('#elem').children().text());
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/8xL7nbgy/)**